# Setting TextView on position x,y

Tags: android, textview, position, touch, screen

Hello I want to display a String on a TextView when the user touches a button. But I want this TextView to be shown on the same position where the user touches the screen. At the moment I have following code but it doesnt work out:

```
private void set(Integer name, Float x, Float y, Typeface font) {

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(10, 1, 10, 1);

    RelativeLayout nlap = new RelativeLayout(this);
    nlap.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setX(x);
    tv1.setY(y);
    tv1.setText("+ " + String.valueOf(name));
    tv1.setTypeface(font);
    tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tv1.setTextSize(20);
    nlap.addView(tv1);

}
```

And in the OnTouchListener:

```
int action = motionEvent.getAction();
            int x = (int)motionEvent.getX();
            int y = (int)motionEvent.getY();
            set(multiplicator, Float.intBitsToFloat(x), Float.intBitsToFloat(y), font);
```

I hope you can help me. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare textView global to that activity

```
TextView tv;
```

then in `oncreate()` method

```
tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_xml_textview);
tv.setText("your desired text");
tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Or you can simply use `android:visibility="invisible"` in your xml

Now `ontouch` of the screen we get the co ordinate and put the textView on that point by below code

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
int corx = (int)event.getX();
int cory = (int)event.getY();
tv.setX(corx);
tv.setY(cory);
tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: okay thanks it works but as I figured out I think the coordinates of the button arent the same as in the whole layout. Can you help me?